# Could we get a view of the top answerers in the last year?

Tags: feature-request, top-users

It seems like we have only two options for viewing the top answerers:

1. Viewing the top answerers of all time.
2. Viewing the top answerers in the last month.

For several reasons, I feel like it would be useful to be able to view the top answerers in the last year. Recruiters may be interested in this. Or people may want to highlight what they were able to achieve in the last year. One month is too short - it tells us that the person is active right now. And all time is too long, since the site has been around since 2009.

Even if the top 5 people don't log in for the next 5 years, they are still likely to remain the top 5 at the end of the next 5 years. So, I feel that there really needs to be an additional list for the top answerers in the last 1 year.

If space is an issue, perhaps it could replace the "Top answerers in the last month" list.

Comment: @ifajra Thanks for the BI link! I succeeded in writing a query which gives me the results. E.g. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/627257/top-answerers-in-c-in-the-last-year for C#. I still think it'd useful to have something like this in a more accessible and authoritative location, though. An HR person who doesn't know SQL may not be able to judge if the query displayed actually displays the top users accurately. "Top users according to Zesty" isn't an authoritative list.